# Add an animation to a simple carousel

Tags: javascript

I have a very simple banner change script:

```
document.getElementById("car_head").innerHTML = carousel[carousel_num][0];
document.getElementById("car_text").innerHTML = carousel[carousel_num][1];
document.getElementById("car_pic").src = carousel[carousel_num][2];
```

This changes the content of my header on a timer.

How can I add a simple animation to it? Would adding a fade in/out animation be different than adding a slide in/out animation?

Thanks,

Comment: Umm.. why are you using plain DOM access when you have jQuery available? `$('#car_head').html(carousel[carousel_num][0]);` would be shorter and nicer (ok, that's subjective).

Comment: @ThiefMaster not everyone wants/needs to use a framework.

Comment: @wambotron, maybe @Thiefmaster's answer has something to do with the question was tagged with 'jquery' tag.

Comment: Didn't notice the tag, but nevertheless, my answer stands. Technically everyone has jQuery available, it doesn't mean you need to use it.

Comment: If it's already embedded there is no reason for not using it. And as DJ said, the question was tagged with jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to loop through it with some form of an animation loop that gradually changes the value you want (alpha, x/y, whatever). For example:

```
var change = function() {
    x -= 10;
    y -= 2;
    styleThese();
    if (x > 10 && y > 0) {
        setTimeout(change, 20);
    }
}

change();
```

Obviously this code doesn't really work. Just work off of that basic idea.